# How to remove duplicate from array of object comparing oldArray to newArray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, object

Let's say I have two arrays and they are:

```js
var oldArray = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'saga', isRunning: false}
];

var newArray = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'mega', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'alpha', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'beta', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'oliverspost', isRunning: true}
];
```

I want to remove all the duplicate object from newArray and replace with 
with the corresponding object with the oldArray. Also any object in oldArray if not present in newArray change its isRunning time to 'True' and push it to the newArray.

Expected Result:

```js
[
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'mega', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'alpha', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'beta', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'daya', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'oliverspost', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'saga', isRunning: true}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried to do this? Also, what defines a duplicate? Just `name` (that's what it looks like), or `name` and `isRunning`? *"...and replace with with the corresponding object with the oldArray."* What does that mean? What I read it to mean doesn't fit with your expected result.

Comment: Have you searched thoroughly? I'm fairly sure this has come up many times and already has good answers.

Comment: In oldArray with object which are unique compared to newArray, need to have control to edit its every key value (in this case isRunning). Here {name: 'saga', isRunning: true} is unique and need to change its isRunning value to TRUE and then push to the newArray.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var oldArray = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
  {name: 'saga', isRunning: false}
];

var newArray = [
  {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'mega', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'alpha', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'beta', isRunning: true},
  {name: 'oliverspost', isRunning: true}
];

newArrayNamesOnly = newArray.map(value => value.name);

oldArray.map(value => {
    let currentName = value.name;
    if (!newArrayNamesOnly.includes(currentName)){
        newArray.push({name: currentName, isRunning: true});
        newArrayNamesOnly.push(currentName);
    }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var oldArray = [
    {name: 'Trump', isRunning: false},
    {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: false},
    {name: 'saga', isRunning: false}
];

var newArray = [
   {name: 'Trump', isRunning: true},
   {name: 'Cruz', isRunning: true},
   {name: 'mega', isRunning: true},
   {name: 'alpha', isRunning: true},
   {name: 'beta', isRunning: true},
   {name: 'oliverspost', isRunning: true}
];


var currentArray = [...oldArray,...newArray]
var obj = {};

for ( var i=0, len=currentArray.length; i < len; i++ )
    obj[currentArray[i]['name']] = currentArray[i];
Object.keys(obj).map((i)=> obj[i])
```

Comment: here the oldArray with object '{name: 'saga', isRunning: false}' is being mapped as it is to the newArray without modification, but I need to change an isRunning value to false for every object which is extra in oldArray compared to newArray.